# How to block access to the .svn/entries on my webserver?

Tags: svn, nginx

I setup an NGINX webserver and use svn to manage project folder. Nessus found the weakness:

> Configure permissions for the affected
>   web server to deny access to the
>   '.svn' directory.

How do I block access to the `.svn` directory? It seems that `svn export` is the more preferable way to checkout on the webserver, but it easier to me to use `svn up`.

Answer (score 8):

finally I found the right way to make it in nginx. Add to nginx.conf this lines in server {} definition:

```
    location ~ /.svn/ {
      deny all;
    }
```

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in a file called ".htaccess" (if you're running Apache):

```
<FilesMatch "^\.svn">
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're under IIS, you can use the method outlined here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/23340/ignoring-svn-directories-under-iis

Answer (score 0):

Quite frankly, I prefer

```
RedirectMatch permanent .*\.(svn|git|hg|bzr|cvs)/.* /
```

To the 404 or 403 errors. That way, the user sees your site root page.